# what's the meaning of "sum to unity"

Tags: meaning

meaning of "sum to unity"?
eg
Relative weights of each factor sum to unity so the overall utility scale (for each decision option) ranges from 0 to 1

Comment: Googling shows this is a statistical term (http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62353/what-does-it-mean-to-use-a-normalizing-factor-to-sum-to-unity), so perhaps it belongs in stats.SE?

Answer (score 3):

The relative weights are all less than one, and will add up to one.

This is the same as percentages that should add to 100.

(Sorry for the brief answer - just a quick one from my phone)